# Java: detecting a color (e.g. is my color blue?)

Tags: java, hsv, threshold

I deal with a project in Java, which loads an image and find color information of each pixel. I need to detect the sky on a color definition, which may seem like the sky - using the blue color range. Originally it seemed best to use RGB, but this necessitates a definition of all shades of blue (uncountable). I found the analysis method, where are used thresholds of HSV for each color, but have no idea how I could load some libraries using color ranges, respectively, how it could be solved. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a `java.awt.Color` to it's HSV values using the static method `RGBtoHSB(...)`. You could then get the hue, and compare it to the boundaries of a range that - for your purposes - constitutes 'blue' - e.g.

```
private static final float MIN_BLUE_HUE = 0.5f; // CYAN
private static final float MAX_BLUE_HUE = 0.8333333f; // MAGENTA

public static boolean isBlue(Color c) {
  float[] hsv = Color.RGBtoHSB(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), null);
  float hue = hsv[0];
  if (hue >= MIN_BLUE_HUE && hue <= MAX_BLUE_HUE){
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}
```

I've offered some starting values for `MIN_BLUE_HUE` and `MAX_BLUE_HUE`, but what you set `MIN_BLUE_HUE` and `MAX_BLUE_HUE` to will depend upon on you're willing to accept as 'blue' - i.e. how much green or purple could there be, and it still be acceptable as sky?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's the same problem, when I use RGB - I must define a range of Hue, Saturation and Value (or brigthess) - combinations which makes a blue color - to write it, that is almost impossible. What i need is some "generator" ("library"), which contains all combinations - table of colors. This "table" I use for compare with concrete pixel with mentioned if.

Comment: @ZbyněkDufka: No - in HSV space, only the hue determines which color it is. Saturation determines how 'white' the color is. Value / brightness determines how 'dark' the color is.